How to Move the cursor one word to the left in ms excel?
In MS Word, Ctrl+left arrow helps use move to the previous word quickly. But the same shortcut in MS Excel takes us to the previous cell. I can't find any shortcuts for the same in the Microsoft's official list of Keyboard shortcuts for Excel either:
MS official list of keyboard shortcuts
Is there any work around for this?

Excel (just as LibreOffice) behaves notably different when

Cell content is "entered" (by just starting typing)
When you EDIT the cell (by first hitting f2)

Test in LibreOffice: CTRL+   ← or → will jump from word to word in the edited cell.

I see, I tried and it works as you said, thanks! But isn't there any work around for the first case, that is, when we're typing. It's not very handy that we can't edit it when we are entering and that we first have to fill the contents and later try to edit it.

Try this: Use f2 to enter also the initial value / formula. I believe this is a special case within the code used to create Excel; I do not know of a "setting" to avoid it.

Great, that's so obvious after you pointed it out, thanks, it works as expected. It's the habit of using Enter key that kept from using F2. Anyways, thanks again!

To move the cursor one word to the left in Microsoft Excel, you can use the following keyboard shortcut:
Press Ctrl + Left Arrow
This shortcut will move the cursor to the beginning of the previous word in the active cell's content. If the cursor is already at the beginning of a word, it will move it to the beginning of the previous word. More details
